# Effective way to find similarity between utterance(short text) and question(long text)

Tags: nlp, similarity, text

The challenge I have is a bunch of questions(long text) that are closely matching with an user utterance (short text). I have tried cosine similarity & Tf-iDF, BM25,Jaccard similarity, etc., but none of these give desired results.

For instance, my question list is
a) how do I transfer from XYZ account
b) will I be able to transfer from XYZ account with zero fees
c) how do I receive some money from XYZ account

utterance - "transfer XYZ account" should result in close similarities between all these.

However an utterance - "transfer XYZ account with some fees" should result in b alone (with other two questions having very less similarity scores)

Another challenge that I face is ordering of these entities. From A --> B is treated similarly as B --> A.

Comment: how about word2vec or bert?

Comment: Thanks for suggesting Nikos - Word2Vec is giving me false positives while BERT gave false negatives.